# Potential Python problem in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64Bit and fuerte?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

currently I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 6 4Bit and ROS fuerte. Unfortunately I noticed several problems by using it. The most weirdest issue is given by executing the roscore which is prompting python failure messages "AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",)".

So if I just start the core by :

```
roscore
```

the system prompts following results:

```
... logging to /home/tlinder/.ros/log/c84ccda0-bc8c-11e1-986c-0024d76d2f84/roslaunch-fhg-thorsten-2827.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://localhost:52473/
ros_comm version <unversioned>

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [2852]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311/

setting /run_id to c84ccda0-bc8c-11e1-986c-0024d76d2f84
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2865]
started core service [/rosout]
```

So as you can see, some python components are crashing and producing this errors:

```
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Edit1:

It seems to be a known bug of [python 2.7](http://bugs.python.org/issue14308) which is still open.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37087/potential-python-problem-in-ubuntu-12.04-lts-64bit-and-fuerte?/) by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 663 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A couple people have been noticing/asking about this issue (http://answers.ros.org/question/34304/exception-attributeerror-when-starting-roscore/?answer=34307#post-id-34307).

Apparently it is a Python-internal bug, which we just need to wait for the fix to be released (both tickets closed):

- ROS ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3950
- Python ticket: http://bugs.python.org/issue14308

(Though, I have to wonder if it is related to any of the hiccups I've been encountering in some of the basic python tutorial/example code, e.g. tf, turtle_tf)

---

Originally posted by [rlinsalata](https://answers.ros.org/users/2578/rlinsalata/) with karma: 271 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4